# Emoji characters appear differently from Figma design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, special-characters, responsive

I'm building an HTML page according to Figma design.

I just copied characters (, ) from the design and put them on my page.

The problem is the characters appear ugly compared to the design.

This is design: https://prnt.sc/pn5ide

This one is the actual result: https://prnt.sc/pn5j2t

Comment: It's up to the OS to display the unicode characters. If you want to show a specific design, use a specific font.

Comment: I set it the same font family(Montserrat) as the design. But it looks different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954940/adam) said on comments different browsers interpret emojis in different ways. You can check [this](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/emoji-compatibility-with-browsers/) to understand better the problem.

Follows an image of how different browser/devices renders different emojis.

> [image]

The only way you could guarantee the same icon is applied independently from browser is to create your the icons and then use them. You can [check](https://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/creating-implementing-icon-font-tutorial/) this to understand how to create your own icons.